# Holt Winters estimation of parameters in R

Tags: r, prediction

Which type of error is R trying to minimise to estimate alpha, beta, gamma when you make a Holt Winters model?

I looked it up in help and here it is stated as "the squared one-step prediction error" which I have never heard of before nor can't seem to find anywhere else.

Might be a simple language question since english is not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike linear regression, for example, where the goal is to make good predictions within the range of the predictors, the goal of time series forecasting is generally extrapolating and making predictions about future periods.  Accordingly the one step ahead error is used and can be calculated by using the data prior to each point in time point to build the model and then calculating the error as the observed value - the predicted value.  The optimization objective function is then to minimize the sum of squared errors across all points (only using points in time where an observed value is available)